# Design pattern with task processor

Tags: design-patterns, factory, abstract

Currently I am working on piece of code which takes data and process it using processor and version. Eg

```
IProcessor aProcessor = new AProcessor(new AProcessorVersion1Translator());
aProcessor.GetResult("sample data");
```

Currently I am using Factory method to get processor according to type:

```
IProcessor aProcessor = processorFactory.GetProcessor("A");
```

Each processor will have various number of version translators, and there is my problem. Where should I use the version translator factory, should I pass it to processor factory object? Or maybe should I create separate factories for each individual processor?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the second solution.
Assuming that each processor has its own list of version translators and maybe each processor may have different methods, I was doing in the following way:

```
IProcessor: no implementation, just use for grouping purpose

ProcessorA: IProcessor
ProcessorB: IProcessor
ProcessorC: IProcessor

Then I was changing the code you wrote to:
var aProcessor = processorFactory.GetProcessor("A") as IProcessorA;
aProcessor.GetVersionTranslator([enum specific to type of Processor])
```

The first solution may be wrong in case a version translator doesn't belong to a specific Processor and then it will required some validation/exception